# Outlook & Gmail not respecting html tag width in newsletter

Tags: html, gmail

I am creating a newsletter from php which outputs the following code.  Although the width of the inside page is fixed to 640px, Outlook and Gmail show it much wider on a big screen.  The same happens to images with fixed width and even height! What should I do to avoid this?

[Link to newsletter.](http://www.african-parks.org/xTemplates/NewsletterPark_01.php?BroadcastEmail_ID=7&VID=0&Mode=)

[Link to what Gmail displays](http://www.african-parks.org/Alpha/Newsletter_Gmail.png)

Comment: As much as it pains me to say it - just use tables and inline styles. It's horrible but you'll get the most consistent results across email clients.

Answer (score 1):

trust me..SpaceBeers is right..i have been creating many newsletters and emailers for past 3 days and for first time i have resorted to table and inline css..It gives perfect accurate results in emails and outlook.i guess Newsletter & Emailers are only reasons why tables are still surviving :D

Comment: Should I just replace each div by a table with 1 row & 1 cell?
Will that also fix the 3rd logo at the bottom being oversized in Outlook?

Comment: try it..if it doesnt works then  a look at the code might b needed